# Is there evidence of Samudrika Shastra being used for selection of kings/spouses et al?

Tags: astrology

From what I understand Samudrika Shastra is like phrenology which is largely discredited in the West.  I read that Kanchi Saankara Matha uses "Samudkrika lakshnas" (among other things) to select the next Shankaracharya.  Is it recorded anywhere else that this Shastra was used for selection?